# How correctly to call the following topic?

Tags: adjectives

**(1)** -*Is Rick here*? -*He **is gone***.
**(2)** -*I **am finished** with that customer. Who's next*?
**(3)** -*Where are you*? -*I **am stopped** at a red light*.

Such using "to be + adjective" as in the examples above is rather hard for me to understand.
I know I can just replace it with "to have + past participle" but I want to understand it literally.
And the problem is that I don't know how to call this in terms of English grammar.
So could you tell me please what grammar term I should type in the google to find the topic about it to not deal with every single case separately but to know the sense of such using as a whole?

---

Usual examples which I understand:
*I **was pleased** after talking to the young lady*. = *Something / someone pleased me*. — most likely "talking to the young lady pleased me" but that's not the point
*I **am** a little **confused** now*. = *Something / someone confused me a little*.
They are quite understandable to me because I perceive them like a passive.

BUT:
*He **is gone**.* ≠ *Something / someone went me*. (a strange sentence)
*I **am finished** with that customer.* ≠ *Something /someone finished me*.
*I **am stopped** at a red light*. ≠ *Something / someone stopped me at a red light*.
Also: *I **am stopped** at a red light*. ≠ *A red light stopped me*. — because for this equality to be true, it must be with "*by*": *I am stopped **by** a red light*. = *A red light stopped me*.
That is, I can't perceive these examples as a passive. That's why they are different from the usual ones.

Comment: They're called *[Past] [**Participle Adjectives***](https://langeek.co/en/grammar/course/626/participle-adjectives). It might help you to understand them if you think about ***modifying a noun*** with a verb - giving you a ***modified noun*** (if you ***steal*** a car, what you end up with is a ***stolen*** car).

Comment: When you say "replace it with '*to have + past participle*'", do you mean without the "to", like, "He **has gone**"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers The examples from the link you gave are: --- "_I **was pleased** after talking to the young lady_.", --- "_I think I **am** a little **confused** now_.", --- "_He **is** always **misunderstood**_." --- I don't know how to explain but they are not those examples which are similar to the ones in my post.

Comment: @Loviii The first two examples are participial adjectives, same as your sentences. The third is passive voice, which is not an example of participial adjectives. That's a mistake from whoever wrote that website.

Comment: @gotube I supplemented the original post in order for you to help me. Thanks.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I supplemented the original post in order for you to help me. Thanks.

Comment: to be stopped at a place is not the transitive verb: The policeman stopped the car.

Comment: Loviii: Your problem seems to be that you assume Past Participle Adjectives can *only* be understood as ***passive verb*** usages. That's why you're having trouble making sense of things. You might think you're "explaining" something like ***I'm bored*** as a passive usage *(some "unspecified agent" bored me),* but that's not a very useful approach. And it doesn't work at all with a truly ***intransitive*** usage like ***I'm finished***, because you can't recast that as *Some unspecified agent finished me*. Don't try to connect passive verbs and participial adjectives so closely.

Answer (score 2):

These are all examples of *participial adjectives* in that context.

When these adjectives follow a "be" verb, they have the same form as the passive voice, but they're not verbs at all.

Though the words are formed from verbs, they are not verbs, and don't convey any action happening. They are truly adjectives. I'll demonstrate that by replacing each one with an adjective, without significantly changing the meaning.

> He is **gone**.
> He is **absent**.
>
> I am **finished** with that customer.
> I am **through** with that customer.
>
> I am **stopped** at a red light.
> I am **stationary** at a red light.

There is no verbal meaning in any of the highlighted words. **All six** of those words are just adjectives.